# Add field for an has_many association with :through

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, has-many-through, has-many

I have a question about `has_many` associations :

Here is a sample of my db/models :

#### Table `document`

```
id   : int
name : text

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :document_pages
    has_many :pages, through: :document_pages
end
```

#### Table `page`

```
id      : int
content : text

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :document_pages
    has_many :documents, through: :document_pages
end
```

#### Table `document_pages`

```
document_id : int
page_id     : int
page_number : int

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pages
    belongs_to :documents
end
```

I am creating the page and the document and I link the two this way :

```
page = Page.create(:content => 'lorem')
document = Document.where(:id => id).first_or_initialize.tap do |document|
    document.pages << page unless document.pages.include?(page)
end
```

And in the line `document.pages << page` I want to provide the field `page_number` of the table `document_pages`.

Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: `document.pages.build(page_number: 1)
    document.pages.save` try this instead of `document.pages << page`

Comment: where do I reference the existing `page` in your solution ?

Comment: Try to run this then I will explain you

Comment: @user123 Thanks.. I was blind.. :p

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'page_number' for Page.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it differently :

```
page = Page.create(:content => 'lorem')

document = Document.where(:id => id).first_or_initialize. do |document|
    document.document_pages.build(page: page, page_number: 1 ) unless document.pages.include?(page)
    document.save!
end
```